# Relationship between $x^*Ax$ and $x^*|A|x$

Tags: matrices

Let $A$ be a Hermitian matrix of order $n\times n$ and $|A|$ denote the matrix containing the absolute values of the corresponding entries of $A$. Let $x$ (with norm$(x)=1$) be an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue $\rho$. Hence we have $$x^*Ax=\rho.$$ Now, is there any comparision relationship exist between $x^*Ax$ and $x^*|A|x$? As $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$, I doubt whether $x^*|A|x$ is always real?

Comment: As $A$ is hermitian we have that $|A|^T=|A|$ since conjugation does not change the modulus of a complex number. Therefore, $\overline{x^*|A|x} =(x^*|A|x)^T$ and so we can conclude $$|x^*|A|x|^2 =  (\overline{x^*|A|x})(x^*|A|x) = (x^*|A|x)^2. $$ Hence $x^*|A|x$ is real.

Comment: $x^*|A|x$ is always real which follows simply from the fact that $A$ is Hermitian, so $|A|$ is real symmetric and hence Hermitian as well and for any Hermitian $B$ and vector $x$, $x^*Bx$ is real.

Comment: I got your point. But I am asking relationship between $x^*Ax$ and $x^*|A|x$, if any exists.